# How can i prevent scaffold from resize it's self when keyboard open EXCEPT a specific widget

Tags: flutter, dart

i have broadcast screen ( in full screen) . i have `textField` on the same broadcast screen on the bottom so we have here `Stack`  like `following`

```
Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children:[
  broadCastScreen()
  TextField()
   ]
  )
)
```

so my layout looks like this

[image]

now when i tap on the text field all scaffold resize its self because of the keyboard show up

the good point in this part that my `textfield`always smoothly move to be up the keyboard visible
but the bad part that my broadcast screen resize its self inappropriately for the user experience

so i decide to prevent that annoying party with set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `false`

well now everything sound good , but i noticed that my keyboard covering my `text field`

so How Can i use `resizeToAvoidBottomInset`to all my widgets except my textfield part ?

i tried to wrap my textfield with another `scaffold` with set `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` to `true`
and `scaffold` color to `transparent` so others widgets be visible and tis work as expected but i completely faced problems with `GestureDetector` pointers in my first `scaffold` and thats because my second `scaffold` stack it

another solution i tried programmatically to set my `textfield` `bottom` `padding` to be the same of my keyboard height using `EdgeInsets.fromWindowPadding(WidgetsBinding.instance.window.viewInsets,WidgetsBinding.instance.window.devicePixelRatio);`

but that's not perfect way because there is some delay with height keyboard value like 900 millisecond to get the keyboard height Furthermore it i tested it on several difference phones and i got null height with some devices It does not guarantee the measurement of all phones

any other perfect way friend ?

Comment: Wrap your Sacffold with padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0),

Comment: it making it worst

Comment: padding:
          EdgeInsets.only(bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom),
Try this

Comment: more worst even . all my scaffold jump

Answer (score 0):

```
 Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        fit: StackFit.expand,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: [
               Content()
          ]
          Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            child: 
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(filled: true, fillColor: 
                  Colors.red
                  ),
                ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Simply Wrap your content in **SingleChildScrollView** and wrap your **TextField** in **Positioned** widget set *bottom* parameter of Positioned to *Zero*, add

```
 fit: StackFit.expand,
```

Note: Don't forget to add above code to your Stack Widget

Comment: i just copied paste your code 
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#f5038 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT

after i edited your code .. keyboard still covering textfield

Comment: are you sure from resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false, ??

Comment: you can try it using resizeToAvoidBottomInset: true. if still got issue show me your code

Comment: the problem is that Camera Broadcast will never accept SingleChildScrollView

Comment: can i have a look at your code?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to do something like this

```
  Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children:[
  Positioned.fill(child:
  broadCastScreen()), 
  Position(
  bottom:0, 
  child: TextField()) 
   ]
  )
)
```